# JAVA - While loop strange output

Tags: java

My assignment is relatively long so I'll try and keep this as brief as possible. I'm personally not new to programming but this Comp Sci class in college has really got me involved. So in one portion of our assignment we are suppose to print out a randomly generated list of maneuvers that will equal up to 5 or 6 points. Generating numbers from 1-22 gets two points and 23-38 gets 1 point. And so I'm suppose to do this ten times. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;


public class Skydive {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    static int score = 0;
    static int round = 0;
    static int maneuvers;
    static Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    static int randomFormations;
    static int blockFormations;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while (round <= 10)
        {

            while (score <= 5)
            {
                maneuvers = randomGenerator.nextInt(38) + 1;

                if (maneuvers <= 22) 
                {
                    score += 2;
                }

                if (maneuvers >= 23)
                {
                    score++;
                }

                System.out.println("Maneuvers done in round: " + maneuvers + " ");

            }
        round++;
        }



    }

}
```

Theres going to be more to the code then just this, but the two while loops is what I'm having problems with.

So one round is suppose to be when the while loop score is equal to 5 or 6 points from the randomly generated maneuvers, and so when that loop is completed, one round is done, and then it is suppose to loop over again and start the next round. I'm suppose to have this print to the console 10 times. However, when I try to execute this, the console prints a set of randomly generated maneuvers, which then suddenly disappears and is replaced with a whole new set; and again, it disappears but one the third time the maneuvers stay on the console screen and the program is "Terminated". Anyone able to help me out so that the console has 10 sets of randomly generated maneuvers all on screen? Thanks guys, if anyone can put it in an easy way that would be great since I'm not great at programming.

Comment: After each round, how does the value of score get back below 5?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the `score`?

Comment: You'll also need to watch your round count if you want 10 times - you're starting at zero

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `score` after each `round`. Something like,

```
while (round < 10) // <-- 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 is 10 values.
{
    score = 0; // <-- or it won't be zero again.
    while (score <= 5)
    {
```

Comment: I think the while loop has to be swapped with a do-while as the objective is to attain a score or either 5 or 6 and the current code might sometimes produce a score of 7

Answer (score 0):

Summing up all the changes required in your code-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Skydive {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int score = 0;
    static int round = 0;
    static int maneuvers;
    static Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    static int randomFormations;
    static int blockFormations;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (round < 10)
    {
        score = 0;
        do
        {
            maneuvers = randomGenerator.nextInt(38) + 1;
            if (maneuvers <= 22) 
            {
                score += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                score++;
            }
            System.out.println("Maneuvers done in round: " + maneuvers + " ");
        } while (score < 5);
        round++;
    }
  }
}
```